# Unable to see WPF Controls Inside the Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, app.xaml

I am working with 10 other people on a VS, C# , Xaml project but recently a branch someone pushed to the master broke the Solution Explorer and I am not able to get it to show the elements under MainWindow.xaml.cs again

No one cares too much about this because the controls are still working if we call them by code and our designers use Blend to edit the design (note: all the controls appear fine in Microsoft Blend for Visual Studio)

But it is troublesome for me to have to open Blend just to adjust a minor design flaw instead of doing it inside Visual Studio directly.

I tried googling but haven't found anything related to my issue yet.

[Working Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy5W2.png)

[Broken Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ3FQ.png)

Comment: Turns out someone on our team fixed the Issue somehow but we couldn't find out who did it and how it was done. Still, an answer would be good for other people who happen to run into the same problem.

Comment: In the "Broken Image Example", it shows properties of Delegates.cs, what is the expectation?.. when you click on "Mainwindow.xaml"  then it shows properties to specific to xaml.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong tab. Properties is not where the issue lies. Look at the solution explorer only. Compare both pictures and you will see that the visual elements inside Mainwindow.xaml are missing. It has nothing to do with its properties.